# Cant Search for Account Parent in my VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, account

When I am searching for a parent account ,there is usually a magnifier glass that allows the users to search for the parent. for some reason my VF page doesn't show the magnifier glass. the code works . If I enter a wrong parent name it will not let me submit and it tells me that its wrong name but the magnifier glass which is suppose to help me search for the parent account name, doesn't display on my page

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!IF($Profile.Name =='test', false , true)}">
        <apex:outputLabel value="Parent Account" for="acctparent" />
        <apex:inputField id="acctparent" value="{!account.ParentId}" />
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Hmm -- works for me (lookup magnifying glass appears) at V36.  Perhaps include a bit more of your VF page

Comment: @cropredy it worked on IE and FF , I guess some how chrome is blocking it on my machine only, you are correct, I tried different browser and its working . can I close this question?

Comment: worked for me on chrome too. You can answer this question yourself and mark it as the solution

Comment: @cropredy Thank you sir All do that, quick question can i do the if statement on role instead of profiles?

Comment: I got the answer for that as well @cropredy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!IF($Profile.Name == 'test', false, true)}">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Parent Account" for="acctparent" />
    <apex:inputField id="acctparent" value="{!account.ParentId}" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

This code is perfectly fine. there was a problem with my Chrome and after restarting and cleaning my browser history and cookies, its showing up.